# HTML link out page

Tags: php, html, href

I am trying to make it so that when someone clicks a link on my site, they will be redirected to an out.php page and then taken to the site the link was aimed at. I wanted to do this so I could display a goodbye message to the user.

I have been looking for a way to do this for a while now but I cannot find any solutions to my problem.

If anyone has any ideas on how I could do this, I would love to know.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What search keywords are you using - there is a *lot* of options and info on Stack, and Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

### out.php

```
<?php 

$url = urldecode($_GET['target']);
echo 'Thank you for visiting, you will be taken to ... in 5 seconds';
echo "<script> setTimeout('window.location = \"$url\";', 5000);</script>";
```

### Normal script

```
echo '<a target="_blank" href="out.php?target=' . urlencode($targetUrl) . '">Click</a>';
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try this

```
<a href="out.php">The LINK</a>
```

when you click on link it will take you to `out.php` where you will display "thank you".
Make sure that `out.php` is in same folder as your html doc else you will have to specify the path where your `out.php` lies.